# Xamarin.forms custom button control

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin.forms

i need to reduce space between buttons [image]

i used buttons for side bar, didn't use list view, if i set height request to reduce the height text will be overlapping, is the any way to reduce height using custom render  or other way ?

this is my code

```
            <!--<Grid BackgroundColor="#783271"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" Text="Client Expertential Plan" TextColor="#636363" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Text="Organisation / Template Library" TextColor="#636363" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="2" Text="Use Expertential Plan" TextColor="#636363" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Italic"/>

            </Grid>-->

            <!--<local:CustomButton Text="hai"></local:CustomButton>-->
            <Button Text="Client Expertential Plan" TextColor="#636363" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
            <Button Text="Organisation / Template Library" TextColor="#636363" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Italic"/>
            <Button Text="Use Expertential Plan" TextColor="#636363" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" BorderWidth="0" BackgroundColor="White" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Italic"/>
            <!--<Label x:Name="lblClientExpPlan"  Text="Client Expertential Plan" TextColor="#737373" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            <Label  x:Name="lblOrgTemLib" Text="Organisation / Template Library" TextColor="#737373" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            <Label  x:Name="lblUseExpPlan" Text="Use Expertential Plan" TextColor="#737373" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>-->
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Stacklayout has its own spacing for its children. Try setting the spacing to 0 for the stacklayout. i.e. spacing =0 for parent stacklayout.

Comment: @Shaw i tried with spacing=0, but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the HeightRequest property as you mention but also reduce the Padding. Android buttons have a large HeightRequest and Padding compared to iOS by default. Try the following:

```
<StackLayout.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button" >
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10, 5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Small" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Start" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#636363" />
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</StackLayout.Resources>

<Button Text="Client Expertential Plan" />
<Button Text="Organisation / Template Library" />
<Button Text="Use Expertential Plan" />
```

The padding property is a recent addition to the Button control. It is present in the Xamarin.Forms 3.2 pre-releases.

Comment: padding course the issue  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10, 5" /> , actually i didn't  saw your last two line of answer Xamarin.forms version may effect, i will check  thanks for your support

Comment: is it affect existing code & function once i update xamarin.forms version ?

Comment: If you already use version 3 I don't think there should be any problems. If you are on version 2 I'm not sure.

Comment: yes it works , when i update xamarin.forms version Thank you